# Error in logistic regression in R: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Tags: r, list, double, logistic-regression

I am attempting to execute a logistic regression in Rstudio using a loaded CSV file that is converted to a dataframe. I have one dependent variable (`result`) and 9 independent variables, which are all in 10 `columns` in the dataframe.

```r
sapply(mydata, mode)

> result cat1 cat2 cat3 cat4 cat5 cat6 cat7 cat8 cat9
> "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric"

sapply(mydata, class)

> result cat1 cat2 cat3 cat4 cat5 cat6 cat7 cat8 cat9  
> "numeric" "integer" "integer" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "factor"

model1 <- glm(formula = result ~ cat3 + cat4 + cat5 + cat6 + cat7 + cat8, 
              data = mydata, 
              family = "binomial")

model1.pred <- ifelse(model1 > 0.5, "Win", "Loss")

> Error in ifelse(win2 > 0.5, "Win", "Loss") : 
> 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Is anyone able to help with why this error is occurring even though all of the variables being used in my model are numeric?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compare `model1` with 0.5

This is model1 structure:

```
model1

Call:  glm(formula = id ~ speed + dist, family = "binomial", data = cars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)        speed         dist  
  -1158.863       73.588        1.366  

Degrees of Freedom: 49 Total (i.e. Null);  47 Residual
Null Deviance:      69.31 
Residual Deviance: 2.932e-08    AIC: 6
```

You have to pass new data to the model and than compare the prediction (using function `predict`) value with 0.5